# How to implement the latest Nativescript theme interface?

Tags: nativescript

I'm using Nativescript theme 2.2

Is the method documented in this page - out of date?

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme

I read the document on the github page...but is there an up to date document in this new interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, documentation is out of date for now - we are working on the new article. You can find updated information about 2.2 in the repo [README](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/blob/master/README.md) and in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/blob/52694a97d1328f08997917148f0990d208ebee1c/MIGRATION-GUIDE.md) which is currently in a PR.

To iterate on your comment what to have in your variables file and app.scss:

To override values and have them available for import in _variables.scss file, you may import the initial variables in there and override them, like this:

```css
@import '~@nativescript/theme/scss/variables';

$accent: red;
$complementary: blue;
```

Then import that file in app.scss (or separately in platform ones - app.ios.scss/app.android.scss) and add the index import after it:

```css
@import 'variables';
@import '~@nativescript/theme/index';
```

This way you can import your variables file wherever you need it without bringing in additional CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. FYI - these out of date documents are very detracting - either there should be a compatible version attached to it or taken offline or a statement that says it's not compatible after a certain revision. I spent hours trying to merge this with the documentation on the github plugin page - didn't make sense.

Comment: It's backward compatible still, include the `.compat` CSS files if you like to use the old way of stylings / class names

Comment: @Bundyo - I read your migration guide for Theme 2. What I'm not clear on still is what files are needed and their contents. For example, I'd like to override some values and am using SCSS. e.g. What should _common, _variables and app.android.scss file contain - in a nutshell.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, as code styling is limited in this comment.